# What happens when you stack "unblockable" and "unblockable except by"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

During a recent game meetup I used [Teleportal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeleportal%5d) to give all my creatures unblockable. Another player responded by targeting one of my creatures with [Shriek of Dread](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShriek%20of%20Dread%5d) to give it "can't be blocked except by artifact creatures and/or black creatures."

We decided (reluctantly in my case) that this might override the unblockable. Our reasoning was that because the revised wording of unblockable is so similar (can't be blocked) the exception would apply to both instances of it.

Are we right?

Comment: Those restrictions don't seem mutually exclusive to me...

Comment: @Jefromi I agree it is not a carbon-copy duplicate, but both are asking after the legality of conflicting "can't be blocked" card text in play, and both answers on that question would be just as appropriate here if you sifted out the scenario-specific bits.

Comment: @winterblood My bad, the title of that question made it sound like it was one about actually mutually exclusive things, where you end up meeting the maximum number of requirements without disobeying restrictions. In this case, you can obey both restrictions at the same time (by not blocking) so they're not actually mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's still just unblockable. There are two restrictions. One will prevent it from being blocked by most things, while leaving artifact creatures and black creatures unrestricted. One won't let it be blocked at all. If nothing blocks it, both restrictions are satisfied, so that's allowed. If a black creature blocked it, one restriction would be violated, so that's not allowed.